# How to integrate html2canvas in webextension?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas, firefox-addon-webextensions

My Firefox WebExtension should be able to take a screenshot of a complete web page. In order to do this i am using `html2canvas`. But when I call this function, the function will never append the canvas element.. (`console.log` will not print as well). And no error exception appears.

**EDIT:** Forgot to link the source for *html2canvas.js*: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas. *html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js* is the script I need for the WebExtension. 
When you add a console.log in *html2canvas/examples/demo.html* or another example, e.g.

```
...
html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        console.log("finished...");
    });
...
```

you will see that `html2canvas` is taking a screenshot successfully and the console logs "finished...".

Can you tell me, what I need to change/ add in the code?

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "description": "capture screen with html2canvas",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "my Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
      "html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.mozilla.org/*"],
      "js": ["content.js", "html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**content.js:** Button within the outer modal. After clicking the button, `html2canvas` will be invoked -> second modal (with the result of `html2canvas`) will be appended

```
var modalOuter = document.createElement("div");
modalOuter.style.width = "100%";
modalOuter.style.height = "100%";
modalOuter.style.position = "fixed";
modalOuter.style.top = 0;
modalOuter.style.left = 0;
modalOuter.style.paddingright = "60px";
modalOuter.style.zIndex = 1000000;
modalOuter.style.overflow = "auto";
var button_TakeShot = document.createElement("button");
button_TakeShot.setAttribute("id", "takeScreenshotButtonID");
button_TakeShot.innerHTML = "Take Screenshot";
modalOuter.appendChild(button_TakeShot);
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(modalOuter);

var modalContent = document.createElement("div");
modalContent.style.backgroundColor = "#fefefe";
modalContent.style.border = "1px solid #888";
modalContent.innerHTML = "Screenshot...";

document.getElementById('takeScreenshotButtonID').addEventListener('click', function() {
    button_TakeShot.style.display = "none"; 
    html2canvas(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0], {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
        console.log("finished...");
        modalContent.appendChild(canvas);
    }
});
modalOuter.appendChild(modalContent);
});
```

Comment: You might want to use `drawWindow`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawWindow

Comment: Please show, or at least link the source for *html2canvas.js*. You state that `html2canvas` is what is not working, but you don't show us how that function is defined. While we might be able to *guess* at what it is, we can't know unless you tell us.

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/captureVisibleTab

Comment: @Alexander `drawWindow` is a good point for the next step. But why do I never get the console output? I think that the function call never get to an end for some reason.
@Daniel I have implemented `tabs.captureVisibleTab()` but in my opinion it is only possible to take a screenshot of the visible area with this function but not of the complete web page (from the top to the end of the page).